# java.net.SocketException: socket closed

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am using socket to send image from server to multiple client but after sending one image to every client again when i try to send another image it say socket is close but i didn't even close the socket as well.

So i want to keep my server and client socket is alive until the activity is visible.

I am using service to run socket server after that i am getting all socket list to activity so below is my code for server side

```
if (mSocketArraylist != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < mSocketArraylist.size(); i++) {
                Socket mSocket = mSocketArraylist.get(i);
                try {
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
                    ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
                    InputStream is = null;
                    try {
                        is = cr.openInputStream(Uri.parse(data.getData().toString()));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                    copyFile(is, out);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("Socket value", "Socket is null");
        }
```

For client also i am using service below its implementation

```
 class clientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (wifiInfo != null) {
            if (!wifiInfo.isGroupOwner) {
                String host = wifiInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
                Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
                OutputStream os = null;

                try {
                    clientSocket.bind(null);
                    clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                    clientSocket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

                    os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);

                    final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                            + SocketClientService.this.getPackageName() + "/VR-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                            + ".jpg");


                    File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                    if (!dirs.exists())
                        dirs.mkdirs();

                    f.createNewFile();

                    while (true) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
                        InputStream inputstream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                        copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
                        break;
                    }
                    signalActivity(f.getAbsolutePath());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());

                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "This device is a group owner, therefore the IP address of the " +
                        "target device cannot be determined. File transfer cannot continue");
            }

        }
    }
}


 public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[8192 * 8192];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So any one can help me out in this , help would be appreciated.

signalActivity method implementation

```
 public void signalActivity(String message) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("message", message);
    clientResult.send(port, b);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the while loop if you are just breaking out at the end of it? Remove the break and put the `signalActivity(f.getAbsolutePath());` at the end of that while loop. Give it a shot and report back.

Comment: You are not closing the client socket indeed. But you are closing the client itself as the thread ends.

Comment: What is signalActivity doing?

Comment: `So i want to keep my server and client socket is alive until the activity is visible.`? Which activity? Where are you talking about? You did tell nothing about an activity.

Comment: `f.createNewFile();`. Remove that statement. Its useless. The file will be created by the new file output stream.

Comment: `dirs.mkdirs();`. Check the return value of mkdirs. It can fail.

Comment: `after that i am getting all socket list to activity`. Unclear what is happening. And why. For what does the activity need that list? Where is your server code executed? You are explaining not enough of your setup.

Comment: `os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);`. You are not using the print writer. Please explain.

Comment: @DillonBurton i have remove that also but not working

Comment: @greenapps PrintWriter y its required

Comment: I agree with @greenapps, we need to at the minimum see what `signalActivity` is doing.

Comment: i have edited my post see the implementation of signalActivity and this method is to send result to activity

Comment: You have not reacted to most of the comments.

Comment: i got the problem if i dont close my out stream that everything working fine but now m getting problem reading file